If $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ then $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx = \infty$
I am trying to prove if  $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ then $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx = \infty$
so $f'\notin L^1$
This came up in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis Section 7.16 (a).
I tried showing;
$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{x}| x^2 \sin(1/x^2)- \cos(1/x^2)| dx=\infty$
with not much luck.
It seems like it should be simple but I am having trouble proving the integral is infinite.
I found some comments on stackexchange of people saying this integral is infinite but I couldn't find a proof.
Things I tried include showing $|\int_0^1 f'(x) dx|=\infty$ which didn't work because I believe this integral is finite, I tried using Jensen's inequality but it is not valid I think in this case, I also tried bounding $|x^2 \sin(1/x^2)-\cos(1/x^2)|$ from below. I noticed $x^2 \sin(1/x^2)\to 0$ as $x \to 0$ so perhaps this could help.

The idea of the following is to estimate the integral $\int |f'(x)| \, dx$ over the interval between a zero and a local extremum of $\sin(1/x^2)$.
For positive integers $k$ set
$$
 x_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1/2)\pi}} \, , \,
 y_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k\pi}} \, .
$$
Then
$$
 0 < x_k < x_k < \cdots < x_1 < y_1 < 1
$$
and $\sin(1/x_k^2) = \pm 1$ and $\sin(1/y_k^2) = 0$, so that
$$
 \frac{1}{(k+1/2) \pi} = |f(y_k) -f(x_k)| \le \int_{x_k}^{y_k} |f'(x)| \, dx \, .
$$
Now $\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx = \infty$ follows from the divergence of the harmonic series.

In other words: Show that $f$ is not of bounded variation.

We have $$f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x^2)-{1\over x}\cos(1/x^2)$$ It suffices to show that $$\int\limits_0^1{1\over x}|\cos(1/x^2)|\,dx=\infty$$ By substitution $x=t^{-1/2}$ we get $$\int\limits_0^1{1\over x}|\cos(1/x^2)|\,dx={1\over 2}\int\limits_1^\infty {|\cos t|\over t}\,dt\\ \ge {1\over 2}\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n\pi}\int\limits_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}|\cos t|\,dy={1\over \pi}\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n}=\infty $$
